# how do you replace NULL values to zero when using mule datamapper?

Tags: sql-server, mule, datamapper

Im trying to set a value to the database but I wanted to default it to zero when I am getting a null value so I can use this as a conditional statement when updating the table values. Any ideas?

Comment: You can also use `ISNULL(value, 0)` in your db layer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ternary operator in the script. Here's an example

```
output.availableSeats = input.seatsAvailable == empty ? 0 : input.seatsAvailable;
```

This snippet sets the available seats to 0 if its empty/null.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition on your datamapper script. 
See sample below:

```
output.outFieldName = input.dbFieldname == null ? 0 : str2integer(input.dbFieldname);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code:

```
output.EarnValue = (isnull(input.balance) ? 0.00 : str2decimal(input.balance))
```